# How to get network routing information from Android Devices?

Tags: android, networking, android-10.0

Android Q is removing access to `/proc/net/` found here: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/data-identifiers.

I need to replace the usage of `/proc/net/route` and `/proc/net/ipv6_route` to collect routing information. But Android suggests using `NetworkStatsManager` and `ConnectivityManager` to replace it. But unable to find routing info from these classes. Am I missing some usage?